# Variable allocation and RAM

Tags: cpu-architecture

Does a number assigned to a variable always fit the allocated amount of RAM ?

Comment: What language are you asking about?  Hardware doesn't have "variables", that's a high-level construct that compilers (or humans writing asm by hand) have to implement.

Comment: Fixed a typo, but your question is simply unclear. You should step back and spend some significant time to improve its quality!

Answer (score 0):

When a variable is initialized, it is initialized on the stack, not the heap. Though both the stack and the heap are part of memory, we usually only talk about allocation with respect to the heap. This is because the stack is controlled entirely by the program running at the time, and no calls to the OS are required to push anything onto it.

All that being said, there is a maximum size the stack can grow to, and once we grow past that size, we have (coincidentally) "stack overflow". So, yes, there is a point at which creating another variable will not fit, but using the term allocation is the wrong way to describe it.